# Implementation about regenerating session id after logging in and logging out

Tags: php, session

I read questions here, security stack exchange, phpsec website and more (can't put all of the links here). I want to implement the **regenerating the session id after logging in and logging out**. To do this, I need to use `session_regenerate_id` if the user is *successfully* logged in and/or logged out. Then what comes to my mind is to put `session_regenerate_id` to login function (after the authentication completes) and also put it to logout function.

example code:

```
public function login(/.../) {

   /..if the authentication completed../
   session_regenerate_id();
   /..Redirects to home page../
}

public function logout(/.../) {
   /..delete the cookie in the database../
   unset($_SESSION[$name]);
   setcookie($name, '', time() - 1);
   session_regenerate_id();
}
```

From what I read in `php.net` it should be used after `session_start()`, but I can't put it on my core file (where `session_start()` can be found) because it will regenerate every time. How can I implement this? Should I call `session_regenerate_id()` after I `require_once 'path/to/my_core_file.php'` in head (start) of the php ?

I really need to implement this to increase the security and `phpsec website` said that using only `session_start()` makes the website vulnerable. Any idea(s) you have there may help me, thank you.

**UPDATE**

Follow up question, is unsetting like this `unset($_SESSION[$name])` will invalidates the session (for logout)?

Comment: Are you using procedural programming or Object oriented programming ?

Comment: `session_regenerate_id` gets used after `session_start`. See the first example https://secure.php.net/session_regenerate_id

Comment: @SumonMahmud Object oriented programming.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Yes, I read that too and it is in my question, that is why I added "Should I `call session_regenerate_id()` before I `require_once 'path/to/my_core_file.php'` in head (start) of the php ?"

Comment: No, your question states that you read that you have to use `session_regenerate_id` **before** `session_start`. But you have to use `session_regenerate_id` **after** `session_start`, so it could be anywhere before you close the session.

Comment: Oh! Yeah I think I misread it, thanks for that! So should I use it after I call `require_once 'path/to/my_core_file.php'` ? Is this line of code will work?

Comment: You can call it in your `login/logout` functions, since that's where you wanna regenerate the ID.

Comment: `unset($_SESSION[$name])` will not invalidate a session, you just unset the variable. Use `session_destroy`. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: Oh, okay I will test this up in a few moment. If you have a time, can you please respond to my update follow up question, thank you.

Comment: Oh okay, `session_destroy` on logout? I will do this.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I quite don't understand this `Whether to delete the old associated session file or not. You should not delete old session if you need to avoid races caused by deletion or detect/avoid session hijack attacks.`. Does this mean that I should not delete old session if I want to avoid session hijack attacks or the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

you can try `uniqid()` function to generate unique id and set it to a session variable like `$_SESSION['user_auth'] = uniqid()` and check it to all authenticate page that

```
if( !empty($_SESSION['user_auth']){
//code or page or redirect to access
}else{
/redirect to login page
}
```

Comment: What I need to do is to regenerate the `session_id()` after successfully logging in and logging out, though thank you for the answer it may help me one way or another.